# Iterate through each child div of a specific class (cheerio)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

I want to get the text for *each* child div **'roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12 palm-1/1'**. I don't know why my code isn't working and I would love some help. I want to *iterate* through each child div (with the name provided above) and add this text (whether it's there or not) to an object.

It is very important that we start from the parent **roster roster-palm 1/1** because there are many other places in the HTML response (that I haven't added) that has the child name.

```
  $('.roster.roster-palm.1\\/1').each((i, el) => {
    el.children.forEach((item) => {
      // find that div here. How do I do it?
      tracking.tracking_update.checkpoints[i].city = item.data.trim()
    })
  })
```

---

```
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-even" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis livr&#233;</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">02/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 12:08</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1"></div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-odd" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">D&#233;part en livraison</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">02/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 08:06</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1">TREMBLAY</div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-even" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Arriv&#233;e &#224; l&#39;agence de destination</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">02/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 06:09</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1">TREMBLAY</div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-odd" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis pris en compte par l'agence TNT</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">01/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 21:08</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1">CAEN</div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-even" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis en cours d&#39;acheminement</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">01/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 20:00</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1"></div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-odd" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis chez l'exp&#233;diteur</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">01/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 00:00</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: *find that div here* -> `item`,  eg `$(item).text()`

Comment: I've tried that but it returns a huge object with lots of data and I have no clue where to go from there.

Comment: Plus there are three children The class '.roster.roster-palm 1\\/1' is everywhere in the HTML

Comment: I want to iterate through each child div and get the text so I can add it to an object. I edited my question.. I.

Comment: Apologies, the names are really confusing - the first issue is your first selector `.roster.roster-palm 1\\/1` - the `1\\/1` needs a class indicator, so need to be `$('.roster.roster-palm.1\\/1')`  (no space as that indicates child)

Comment: But if you specially want `4/12` only, then no need for `.children()` - use `$('.roster.roster-palm.1\\/1 .4\\/12').each((i,e) => data[i] = $(e).text()`

Comment: No problem :) The names are really confusing, really bad HTML from an API. I had an original solution like your last comment, but there are other divs with the name '```'.roster.roster-palm.1\\/1 .4\\/12'``` outside the HTML I provided. So we always have to start from the ```parent roster roster-palm 1/1```. My question wasn't worded correctly to begin with, sorry. I have edited it further.

Comment: "always have to start from the parent" - please include the parent and how you access it / how you want to get data from the "parent" - this currently isn't in your code - is "roster" the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the `4/12` children of `1\\/1` items in a single selector.  To ensure you only get direct children, use `>` instead of

```
$('.roster.roster-palm.1\\/1>.4\\/12')
```

then loop through those.

Alternative, the index for `.roster` is important (as indicated in the comments), then you can use `.find`, using `>` in the `.find` selector will ensure only direct-children are selected.

```
$('.roster.roster-palm.1\\/1").each((i,e) => {
    // for info: var roster = e;
    $(e).find(">.4\\/12").each((ii,ee) => {
        tracking.tracking_update.checkpoints[i].city = $(e).text();
    }
});
```

```js
var data=[];
$('.roster.roster-palm.1\\/1>.4\\/12').each((i, el) => {
    data[i] = $(el).text();
})
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='4/12'>not included</div>
 
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-even" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis livr&#233;</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">02/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 12:08</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1"></div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-odd" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">D&#233;part en livraison</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">02/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 08:06</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1">TREMBLAY</div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-even" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Arriv&#233;e &#224; l&#39;agence de destination</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">02/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 06:09</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1">TREMBLAY</div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-odd" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis pris en compte par l'agence TNT</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">01/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 21:08</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1">CAEN</div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-even" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis en cours d&#39;acheminement</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">01/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 20:00</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1"></div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-odd" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis chez l'exp&#233;diteur</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">01/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 00:00</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to start from ```.roster.roster-palm.1\\/1``` and not from the child because this child class is in other parts of the code (not added) which I don't need.

Comment: You can start with the child, then get *back* to the .roster parent using `$(el).closest(".roster")` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to get the classes on each child element. Then use the [DOMTokenList.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains) method to filter the child elements based on their classes.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you have a space in your selector.

`$('.roster.roster-palm 1\\/1')` so jquery is trying to look for the element `1/1` but ofc there is no such element, so use `$('.roster.roster-palm.1\\/1')`;

**DEMO**

```js
console.log("Elements found with .roster.roster-palm 1\\/1 .4\\/12 is: "+$('.roster.roster-palm 1\\/1 .4\\/12').length)

console.log("Elements found with .roster.roster-palm.1\\/1 .4\\/12 is: "+$('.roster.roster-palm.1\\/1 .4\\/12').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-even" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis livr&#233;</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">02/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 12:08</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1"></div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-odd" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">D&#233;part en livraison</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">02/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 08:06</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1">TREMBLAY</div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-even" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Arriv&#233;e &#224; l&#39;agence de destination</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">02/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 06:09</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1">TREMBLAY</div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-odd" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis pris en compte par l'agence TNT</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">01/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 21:08</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1">CAEN</div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-even" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis en cours d&#39;acheminement</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">01/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 20:00</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1"></div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-odd" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis chez l'exp&#233;diteur</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">01/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 00:00</div>
  <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Benjamints I've updated the code you can use `$('.roster.roster-palm.1\\/1 .4\\/12')`